# Desktop login fails, terminal works

Tags: virtualbox, lightdm, login-screen, pam

I have a freshly setup 12.04 LTS pc system (120 GB SSD, 1 TB HDD, 16 GiB RAM); since a few days, I can't login to the graphical desktop anymore: there is very short flashing shell window which disappears very quickly (**edit: see below**), and I'm confronted with the login screen again. I believe there is something about `modprobe` and `vbox`, but I can't read it fast enough ...

I can login to a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>). It did not help to chown all contents of my home directory to `me`:`my-group`, like suggested [here](/questions/140652/12-04-desktop-login-loop).

This is what I could find in `/var/log`, grepping for the date and time (I inserted linebreaks after `<my-hostname>`; real time values preserved):

auth.log:

```
<date> 22:43:01 <my-hostname>
    lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "tobias"
<date> 22:43:08 <my-hostname>
    lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session closed for user lightdm
<date> 22:43:08 <my-hostname>
    lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user tobias by (uid=0)
<date> 22:43:08 <my-hostname>
    lightdm: pam_ck_connector(lightdm:session): nox11 mode, ignoring PAM_TTY :0
<date> 22:43:08 <my-hostname>
    lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session closed for user tobias
<date> 22:43:09 <my-hostname>
    lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
<date> 22:43:09 <my-hostname>
    lightdm: pam_ck_connector(lightdm:session): nox11 mode, ignoring PAM_TTY :0
<date> 22:43:10 <my-hostname>
    lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "tobias"
<date> 22:43:10 <my-hostname>
    dbus[756]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender="1:43" (uid=104 pid=1639 comm="/usr/lib/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-ser") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.15" (uid=0 pid=1005 comm="/usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon ")
```

kern.log:

```
<date> 22:43:00 <my-hostname>
    kernel: [   16.084525] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
```

syslog:

```
<date> 22:43:00 <my-hostname>
    kernel: [   16.084525] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
<date> 22:43:01 <my-hostname>
    ntpdate[1492]: adjust time server 91.189.94.4 offset -0.162831 sec
<date> 22:43:08 <my-hostname>
    acpid: client 969[0:0] has disconnected
<date> 22:43:08 <my-hostname>
    acpid: client connected from 1553[0:0]
<date> 22:43:08 <my-hostname>
    acpid: 1 client rule loaded
```

I have Virtualbox and Truecrypt installed, but I can't think of a reason why they might prevent a graphical login.

I'm confused:

- What is this about `requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met`? I *do* login using a password, and the password works ok when logging in to a terminal!
- Can I somehow read the error output, e.g. by delaying it, redirecting it to a file, or having the system prompt me for pressing a key?
- Has possibly any recent update caused my problem? Should I install the pending updates? *How*, btw, without access to the graphical UI?

I have some working knowledge about the Linux shell, but I'm new to Ubuntu. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** After shutting down the machine yesterday (`sudo shutdown now`), I found the following text on the screen, which appears to be the "flashing" text mentioned before (formatted; there was some silly leading whitespace):

```
Could not write bytes: broken pipe
speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speed-dispatcher
* Starting VirtualBox kernel modules
* modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why
saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned
* Checking battery state... [ OK ]
```

After manually copying it, I switched the machine off by pressing the button several seconds.

Might be that virtualbox (4.2 installed) causes the problem. I'll add some more log file extractions later today (MET).

**Edit**, for the records:
I tried the following, from /a/133754/103086:

- `sudo apg-get install gdm` (when prompted, chose `GDM`)
- rebooted; login failed with GDM, too
- `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`, rebooted; login won't work
- my `~/.Xauthority` file is empty; deleting it and rebooting didn't change anything

Furthermore:

- deinstalled virtualbox (`sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-4.2`), rebooting

**Edit**: I uploaded a zip archive of selected/filtered log files to http://www.tobias-herp.de/en/errors/ubuntu-gui-lockout. Kept `apt-get upgrade`ing recently, but unfortunately the problem persists.

Comment: I have a script to extract log lines now (and copy files with non-prefixed lines), and I'd upload a zip archive (since it would be 1619 lines in 6 files, including 924 lines in `dmesg`), but I can't find out how to upload it ...

Comment: Could this http://tweek-it-up.blogspot.com/2012/08/ubuntu-1204-login-screen-appears-even.html   be it?

Comment: Nope; the `~/.Xauthority` file is completeliy "mine" (`tobias:tobias`).

Comment: I recently setup a new 12.04 desktop (already have 5 others) and the new one was running into problems login into the GUI with ldap users, but not local.  I struggled with it with limited success, then gave up and installed Mint which worked.  I'm guessing there is some kind of regression in a recent update.  rant: ubuntu is becoming a complete mess.  just look at the crazy pam setup with configuration tools that are even more complicated and arcane than manual pam configuration.

Comment: [OP reinstalled the system](http://askubuntu.com/a/215557/169736)

Answer (score 14):

Removing ~/.Xauthority worked for me

Comment: Same here, even if the ``~/.Xauthority`` was with right permission and right owner (me).

Comment: Likewise this worked for me (on Ubuntu 13.04)

Comment: Yes, removing the file is necessary because the data in the .Xauthority file will differ (perhaps there is a pid or date context?).  Permission alone is not the usual problem.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue.  It turned out that my problem was that `~/.Xauthority` was updated as root, and from then on only root could read it. It stopped me from starting any X session from my username.  I had to `sudo rm ./.Xauthority` and it worked fine after that.

Answer (score 3):

I finally gave up and reinstalled the system. This was not a problem, since the system was quite fresh, and most personal data was not yet migrated to it. I can't tell for sure the problem was not caused by a non-standard package, so ...

So I started anew, and I took precautions to be better off next time.
After installation, I updated the system, installed some crucial packages and pinned an eye to the configuration:

```
sudo bash
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install ssh mercurial vim
cd /etc/
vim mercurial/hgrc
hg init .
hg add *
hg commit
```

Thus, whenever a new problem occurs, I should stand a better chance to know what might have gone wrong.

Comment: Just for the records: after a while, even the newly setup system run into the same problem.  I decided to remove Ubuntu totally and installed Windows instead (with a virtual Linux machine).

Comment: Just for the records: what you do with "hg" is done automatically thanks to the package "etckeeper" (and you can choose mercurial, bazaar, git...)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this was caused by a wrong `~/.dmrc` as explained [here](http://www.kubuntuforums.net/archive/index.php/t-59153.html). This can be detected thanks to `~/.xsession-errors` where I had the following error:

> x-terminal-emulator: Fatal IO error: client killed konsole(1598)
>   Konsole::SessionManager::~SessionManager: Konsole SessionManager
>   destroyed with sessions still alive

Comment: worked for me too. Kubuntu 12.04, KDE. I deleted both .dmrc and.Xauthority. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A similar problem happened to me after I added an `export PATH=$PATH:/home/<user>/SomeFolder` to the end of `/etc/profile`. After I logged into a terminal, removed that line and rebooted, I could login normally and the problem seems to have gone away.

Documentation:

- I was getting the following flashing text on the screen before the login screen:

  ```
  Could not write bytes: broken pipe
  * Starting VirtualBox kernel modules

  saned disabled; edit /etc/default/saned
  ```
- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 64-bit, Intel Core i5, 6GB.
- I have VirtualBox 4.2.18 installed but it seems to be working just fine.
- I dual boot with Windows 8 using GRUB.

Comment: Could this have been the problem? I don't know. I usually have a `~/bin` directory which I like to have in the `PATH`, but the installation doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: You pushed me into the right direction when solving the problem which appeared on my netbook as well, which still has Ubuntu. One of the shellscripts I sourced automatically during login caused an error, and there as a line in `~/.xsession-errors`; when I tried it in a shell, all looked ok. However, I disabled loading the scripts, and I can login graphically again.

Answer (score 0):

Running into this now using lightdm + any non unity greeter.  If I set the greeter to unity-greeter in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf, it seems to work.  No idea why.

Edit:  redacted.  Something I just pulled in with an update must have caused this and now even the unity greeter doesn't work.

Comment: I had a look at this file; in (the one and only) section `SeatDefaults`, the value of the `greeter-session` is `unity-greeter` already. Any other value I could try?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added some commands into .xprofile
which caused the return back to login-screen right after login.
The errors I found were the same.
Remove everything non-essential from your ~/.profile and ~/.xprofile should bring the situation back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

For me this happened when there is some invalid path entry make in .profile file. When I removed it, it worked perfectly. Check your .xsession-error file for the error it reports

Answer (score 0):

There was the same error for me on Ubuntu 14.04.02 LTS. I have opened log file `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log` and see message like `...not enough disk space for .Xauthroity...`. Then I have found that there is really zero space on disk. So I have removed some files and bug disappeared.