# Unable to sign in. How to debug?

Tags: 12.04, xorg, lightdm, login-screen

I had to reboot system with reset button. After reboot I can't sign in. When I enter my password It seems like X-server just restarts.

I can sign-in as guest and also I can sign-in in text TTY. Here is first 150 lines of my lightdm.log:

```
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Starting Light Display Manager 1.2.1, UID=0 PID=1070
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Loaded configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Using D-Bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xlocal
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xremote
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Adding default seat
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Starting seat
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Starting new display for automatic login as user dmytro
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Starting local X display
[+3.64s] DEBUG: X server :0 will replace Plymouth
[+3.66s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+3.66s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+3.66s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+3.66s] DEBUG: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+3.66s] DEBUG: Launching X Server
[+3.66s] DEBUG: Launching process 1154: /usr/bin/X :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch -background none
[+3.66s] DEBUG: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
[+3.66s] DEBUG: Acquired bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+3.66s] DEBUG: Registering seat with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
[+10.78s] DEBUG: Got signal 10 from process 1154
[+10.78s] DEBUG: Got signal from X server :0
[+10.78s] DEBUG: Stopping Plymouth, X server is ready
[+10.80s] DEBUG: Connecting to XServer :0
[+10.80s] DEBUG: Automatically logging in user dmytro
[+10.80s] DEBUG: Started session 1303 with service 'lightdm-autologin', username 'dmytro'
[+13.22s] DEBUG: Session 1303 authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+13.26s] DEBUG: Autologin user dmytro authorized
[+13.27s] DEBUG: Autologin using session ubuntu
[+14.44s] DEBUG: Dropping privileges to uid 1000
[+14.48s] DEBUG: Restoring privileges
[+14.49s] DEBUG: Dropping privileges to uid 1000
[+14.49s] DEBUG: Writing /home/dmytro/.dmrc
[+14.61s] DEBUG: Restoring privileges
[+14.81s] DEBUG: Starting session ubuntu as user dmytro
[+14.81s] DEBUG: Session 1303 running command /usr/sbin/lightdm-session gnome-session --session=ubuntu
[+15.76s] DEBUG: New display ready, switching to it
[+15.76s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+15.76s] DEBUG: Registering session with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
[+16.63s] DEBUG: Session 1303 exited with return value 0
[+16.63s] DEBUG: User session quit
[+16.63s] DEBUG: Stopping display
[+16.63s] DEBUG: Sending signal 15 to process 1154
[+17.19s] DEBUG: Process 1154 exited with return value 0
[+17.19s] DEBUG: X server stopped
[+17.19s] DEBUG: Removing X server authority /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+17.19s] DEBUG: Releasing VT 7
[+17.19s] DEBUG: Display server stopped
[+17.19s] DEBUG: Display stopped
[+17.19s] DEBUG: Active display stopped, switching to greeter
[+17.19s] DEBUG: Switching to greeter
[+17.19s] DEBUG: Starting new display for greeter
[+17.19s] DEBUG: Starting local X display
[+17.19s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+17.19s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+17.19s] DEBUG: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+17.19s] DEBUG: Launching X Server
[+17.19s] DEBUG: Launching process 1563: /usr/bin/X :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
[+17.19s] DEBUG: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
[+17.48s] DEBUG: Got signal 10 from process 1563
[+17.48s] DEBUG: Got signal from X server :0
[+17.48s] DEBUG: Connecting to XServer :0
[+17.48s] DEBUG: Starting greeter
[+17.48s] DEBUG: Started session 1575 with service 'lightdm', username 'lightdm'
[+17.61s] DEBUG: Session 1575 authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+17.61s] DEBUG: Greeter authorized
[+17.61s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log
[+17.68s] DEBUG: Session 1575 running command /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session /usr/sbin/unity-greeter
[+20.86s] DEBUG: Greeter connected version=1.2.1
[+20.86s] DEBUG: Greeter connected, display is ready
[+20.86s] DEBUG: New display ready, switching to it
[+20.86s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+20.86s] DEBUG: Stopping greeter display being switched from
[+24.90s] DEBUG: Greeter start authentication for dmytro
[+24.90s] DEBUG: Started session 1746 with service 'lightdm', username 'dmytro'
[+25.10s] DEBUG: Session 1746 got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+25.10s] DEBUG: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
[+31.87s] DEBUG: Continue authentication
[+33.75s] DEBUG: Session 1746 authentication complete with return value 7: Authentication failure
[+33.75s] DEBUG: Authenticate result for user dmytro: Authentication failure
[+33.75s] DEBUG: Greeter start authentication for dmytro
[+33.75s] DEBUG: Session 1746: Sending SIGTERM
[+33.75s] DEBUG: Started session 2264 with service 'lightdm', username 'dmytro'
[+33.75s] DEBUG: Session 2264 got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+33.75s] DEBUG: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
[+36.41s] DEBUG: Continue authentication
[+36.53s] DEBUG: Session 2264 authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+36.53s] DEBUG: Authenticate result for user dmytro: Success
[+36.54s] DEBUG: User dmytro authorized
[+36.54s] DEBUG: Greeter requests session ubuntu
[+36.54s] DEBUG: Using session ubuntu
[+36.54s] DEBUG: Stopping greeter
[+36.54s] DEBUG: Session 1575: Sending SIGTERM
[+37.41s] DEBUG: Greeter closed communication channel
[+37.41s] DEBUG: Session 1575 exited with return value 0
[+37.41s] DEBUG: Greeter quit
[+37.42s] DEBUG: Dropping privileges to uid 1000
[+37.42s] DEBUG: Restoring privileges
[+37.43s] DEBUG: Dropping privileges to uid 1000
[+37.43s] DEBUG: Writing /home/dmytro/.dmrc
[+38.35s] DEBUG: Restoring privileges
[+40.37s] DEBUG: Starting session ubuntu as user dmytro
[+40.37s] DEBUG: Session 2264 running command /usr/sbin/lightdm-session gnome-session --session=ubuntu
[+40.39s] DEBUG: Registering session with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session1
[+50.78s] DEBUG: Session 2264 exited with return value 0
[+50.78s] DEBUG: User session quit
[+50.78s] DEBUG: Stopping display
[+50.78s] DEBUG: Sending signal 15 to process 1563
[+51.53s] DEBUG: Process 1563 exited with return value 0
[+51.53s] DEBUG: X server stopped
[+51.53s] DEBUG: Removing X server authority /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+51.53s] DEBUG: Releasing VT 7
[+51.53s] DEBUG: Display server stopped
[+51.53s] DEBUG: Display stopped
[+51.53s] DEBUG: Active display stopped, switching to greeter
[+51.53s] DEBUG: Switching to greeter
[+51.53s] DEBUG: Starting new display for greeter
[+51.53s] DEBUG: Starting local X display
[+51.53s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+51.53s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+51.53s] DEBUG: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+51.53s] DEBUG: Launching X Server
[+51.53s] DEBUG: Launching process 2894: /usr/bin/X :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
[+51.53s] DEBUG: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
[+51.75s] DEBUG: Got signal 10 from process 2894
[+51.75s] DEBUG: Got signal from X server :0
[+51.75s] DEBUG: Connecting to XServer :0
[+51.75s] DEBUG: Starting greeter
[+51.75s] DEBUG: Started session 2898 with service 'lightdm', username 'lightdm'
[+51.76s] DEBUG: Session 2898 authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+51.76s] DEBUG: Greeter authorized
[+51.76s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log
[+51.76s] DEBUG: Session 2898 running command /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session /usr/sbin/unity-greeter
[+53.26s] DEBUG: Greeter connected version=1.2.1
[+53.26s] DEBUG: Greeter connected, display is ready
[+53.26s] DEBUG: New display ready, switching to it
[+53.26s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+53.26s] DEBUG: Stopping greeter display being switched from
[+54.17s] DEBUG: Greeter start authentication for dmytro
[+54.17s] DEBUG: Started session 3152 with service 'lightdm', username 'dmytro'
[+54.18s] DEBUG: Session 3152 got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+54.18s] DEBUG: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
[+58.61s] DEBUG: Continue authentication
[+58.65s] DEBUG: Session 3152 authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+58.65s] DEBUG: Authenticate result for user dmytro: Success
[+58.66s] DEBUG: User dmytro authorized
[+58.66s] DEBUG: Greeter requests session ubuntu
[+58.66s] DEBUG: Using session ubuntu
[+58.66s] DEBUG: Stopping greeter
[+58.66s] DEBUG: Session 2898: Sending SIGTERM
```

How can I fix it? What other .log files could possibly give me a clue?

**Update:** Possibly it's duplicate of [Desktop login fails, terminal works](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210480/desktop-login-fails-terminal-works)

Comment: Good log file you provided. Try to delete `.Xauthority` . It is a re-created file. `rm .Xauthority`

Comment: If you mean ~/.Xauthority than it doesn't help :(

Comment: what about ~/.xsession-errors ?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1357664

Comment: that was a ~/.profile that I screwed up.

Comment: [What is .xsession-errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222449/what-is-xsession-errors) is quite helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might have erroneously mistyped some bash command alias, according to your logs, since the issue seems to be linked to your userspace. You may want to replace your `~/.bashrc` with the default one, e.g. from `/etc/skel/.bashrc`. Make sure to have a backup copy prior to that. You could actually direct your ~/.profile to any accessible file. Your could also make `~/.bashrc` a symlink.

Make sure to actually read personally your ~/.profile, there's so much information. And `man bash` will answer so many questions you won't find any answers if you had on the net.

If you're more or also interested in debugging, run prior to replacing for the sake of chance

`cat ~/.bashrc | grep "[["`

`cat /etc/bash_completion | grep "[["`

You could also see what else may be wrong: 
`diff /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc`

Comment: As I stated in comments earlier w/ help of martin-mystere I found a problem in ~/.profile That was close to your solution, but I can't accept it.

Comment: From your prespective your question may have received an answer you consider a solution. In such case you are expected to make this evident.

Comment: And may I please learn of the reasons for the two downvotes one of which has been taken back?

Comment: I'm sorry. I downvoted as question was resolved in comments at the time of your answer. And I did't liked it to be too verbose. Acctual fix was: `mv ~/.profile /tmp/`