# Ubuntu raring 13.04 x64 AMD Radeon HD 7500M/7600M fglrx issue

Tags: ati, 64-bit, radeon, fglrx

I finished install my fresh Ubuntu 13.04 x64 and would like install fglrx (ATI driver).
But, I tried install the new AMD proprietary 13.4 and got a low graphics mode after reboot.

When I install both fglrx or fglrx-updates the system don't boot. When I was using the precise version I installed with success through repository `ppa:andrikos/ppa` in x86 version.

Can someone help me out?

Here is my lspci output:

```
christopher@inspiron:~$ lspci

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
**00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)**
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
**02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Thames [Radeon 7550M/7570M/7650M]**
07:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet (rev 10)
```

Comment: I was able to get some sort of function out of mine using the x.org driver along with the solution offered here http://askubuntu.com/a/285822/82517

Answer (score 1):

Have a read through this as it it's very complete

http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Raring_Installation_Guide

You should be able to get everything working by carefully following the instructions. Though I'd follow all of the un-installation steps first to get your install back to the open source drivers and in a working state before trying again.

Sound probably won't work though as I can't get any audio at all right now and the 'sound card' in my GPU is not detected. Not very happy right now. Should have stuck with 12.10 which worked with no issues.

Comment: After reading trough and some further research I think that this is the bug previously fixed by the  Andrikos PPA in 12.10 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1068404

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be the relevant bug report - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-ati/+bug/1173217

A user comment that trying Ubuntu 13.10 (Daily build) fixes the issue.