# No icons or bars show up in the desktop, after a recent Ubuntu 13 update

Tags: icons

Since a recent Ubuntu update, I have the problem that no icons show up in the desktop (no possibility for me to launch any program / software centre from the desktop...

How could I solve this? Would installing "vanilla Ubuntu 13.04" work?

How to do this from terminal? 
I tried typing `sudo apt-get vanilla Ubuntu 13.04` 
but does not work.

Comment: Try `sudo startx`

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your question only, I can suspect it's got something to do with your graphic card. Please have a look at this thread:

[After upgrading to 13.04 Unity interface is not showing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285779/after-upgrading-to-13-04-unity-interface-is-not-showing)