# When Cinnamon is installed, Unity desktop "smears" (doesn't refresh) and shows no wallpaper

Tags: unity, graphics, display, desktop-background

Since a couple of days now, my unity desktop background smears everything, just like what old Windows versions were famous for:

[image: smeared desktop]

Of course, I tried rebooting a couple of times. Also, I switched graphics driver and I tried to change wallpaper and theme, but none of them solved the problem.

What could be causing that problem, and where can I search on for its source?

**Infomation update**

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 (not updated to 13.10 yet).

*The following commands were all run from cinnamon (on the same Ubuntu installation).*

`sudo lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.04
Release:    13.04
Codename:   raring
```

`sudo uname -a`:

```
Linux cedric-MacBookPro 3.8.0-32-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 22:35:23 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`sudo dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-video`:

```
ii  xserver-xorg-video-all                    1:7.7+1ubuntu4                         amd64        X.Org X server -- output driver metapackage
ii  xserver-xorg-video-ati                    1:7.1.0-0ubuntu2                       amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI display driver wrapper
ii  xserver-xorg-video-cirrus                 1:1.5.2-0ubuntu1                       amd64        X.Org X server -- Cirrus display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-fbdev                  1:0.4.3-0ubuntu1                       amd64        X.Org X server -- fbdev display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel                  2:2.21.6-0ubuntu4.3                    amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-mach64                 6.9.3-0ubuntu1                         amd64        X.Org X server -- ATI Mach64 display driver
ii  xservhttps://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1244237er-xorg-video-mga                    1:1.6.2-0ubuntu1                       amd64        X.Org X server -- MGA display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-modesetting            0.7.0-0ubuntu2                         amd64        X.Org X server -- Generic modesetting driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-neomagic               1:1.2.7-0ubuntu1                       amd64        X.Org X server -- Neomagic display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau                1:1.0.7-0ubuntu1                       amd64        X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-openchrome             1:0.3.1-0ubuntu1.13.04.1               amd64        X.Org X server -- VIA display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-qxl                    0.1.0-0ubuntu3                         amd64        X.Org X server -- QXL display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-r128                   6.9.1-0ubuntu1                         amd64        X.Org X server -- ATI r128 display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-radeon                 1:7.1.0-0ubuntu2                       amd64        X.Org X server -- AMD/ATI Radeon display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-s3                     1:0.6.5-0ubuntu3                       amd64        X.Org X server -- legacy S3 display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-savage                 1:2.3.6-0ubuntu1                       amd64        X.Org X server -- Savage display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion          1:1.7.7-0ubuntu1                       amd64        X.Org X server -- SiliconMotion display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-sis                    1:0.10.7-0ubuntu1                      amd64        X.Org X server -- SiS display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb                 1:0.9.6-0ubuntu1                       amd64        X.Org X server -- SiS USB display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-tdfx                   1:1.4.5-0ubuntu1                       amd64        X.Org X server -- tdfx display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-trident                1:1.3.6-0ubuntu2                       amd64        X.Org X server -- Trident display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vesa                   1:2.3.2-0ubuntu1                       amd64        X.Org X server -- VESA display driver
ii  xserver-xorg-video-vmware                 1:12.0.2+git.e5ac80d8-0ubuntu1         amd64        X.Org X server -- VMware display driver
```

`sudo lspci | grep VGA`:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT216M [GeForce GT 330M] (rev a2)
```

**Update 2**

This bug might be related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1244237

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using.. It would be good if you provide the output of these commands: `sudo lsb_release -a`, `sudo uname -a`, `sudo dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-video` and `sudo lspci | grep VGA`

Comment: Okay, edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By now, I've had the same issue on two different machines. On the first one, it solved itself with a distribution upgrade. On the other one, I followed comment #10's tip in this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1244237

```
sudo apt-get purge cinnamon
```

This command uninstalls Cinnamon (Mint's desktop environment), including Nemo, and deletes all configuration.

Apparently, this problem was related to Cinnamon/Nemo, or the fact that probably two different desktop environments/file managers (Unity/Nautilus and Cinnamon/Nemo) tried to manage destop backgrounds, but I don't know any details.

**Update**

[This article](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html) features a version of Nemo for Unity without Cinnamon.

Comment: There is no need to purge cinnamon.
You just need to kill nemo and start nautilus instead.
$ killall nemo
$ nautilus

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem as you (Ubuntu 13.04 on a Zenbook Prime) and found your question when searching for an answer. I found it 5 minutes ago (here, on this [topic](https://askubuntu.com/a/285822/196346)):

Resetting Compiz with the command `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` and then, logging out and in, using `gnome-session-quit`. That did the trick: the background image reappeared and the refreshing problems disappeared.

Comment: Hmm, I think I already tried this one. But I cannot be sure right now, since I don't have the problematic computer here...

Comment: A few months later, I had the regrets to see that this solution wasn't definitive. My problem came back many times. The real solution for me was to uninstall Cinnamon (that I installed but finally didn't use) which was apparently making some conflict with Gnome. Do you have other window managers?

Comment: Roughly the similar problem on a Zenbook prime which typically stops recognizing the second display after a while. I'll then force it to connect with xrandr - after which I'll lose my background (12.04) or it even starts smearing (14.04)