# Blank Desktop after upgrade

Tags: upgrade

Just upgraded to 13.10, no desktop icons/menu, just the wallpaper.

I've tried :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot

sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Its not a duplicate if that answered question doesn't solve it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've actually just spent the last two days fixing this problem myself. I was running 13.04 and had it happen suddenly and mysteriously, I re installed from a 12.04 disk and upgraded back up to 13.04 with the same problem continuing.

I found a lot of useful solution suggestions here and here:

[Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

[After upgrading to 13.04 Unity interface is not showing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285779/after-upgrading-to-13-04-unity-interface-is-not-showing)

None of solutions in the first post fixed mine however and I ended up fixing it with:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
sudo gnome-session-quit
```

then logging back in. Though it would have made sense for that to have installed gnome it seemed to instead have fixed unity and now is running like a charm.