# Nothing shows up

Tags: unity

Just restarted my computer and this happens, tried switching desktop managers and the same thing. Help?

[image]

Comment: You can install Compiz Config Settings Manager and play with enabling/disabling Unity plugin.

Comment: Try the above question, then, if it doesn't work, report back here (by *editing* your question). What graphics card do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Step #1 = After logging in to the blank desktop press "control + alt + t". This will open a terminal.

Step #2 = In terminal type "sudo start lightdm". This will start lightdm, and prompt you to login again.

Step #3 = When logging in click the Ubuntu logo and verify it's logging you into "ubuntu" rather than a fallback session. After logging in you should see Unity running. If not you may have a configuration issue, and should proceed to step 4.

Step #4 = In terminal type "sudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf". This will open the configuration file for lightdm. The file should read nothing on line one, "[SeatDefaults]" on line 2, "user-session=ubuntu" on line 3, and "greeter-session=unity-greeter" on line 4.

This post may also be an interesting read depending which version of ubuntu you have: [After upgrading to 13.04 Unity interface is not showing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285779/after-upgrading-to-13-04-unity-interface-is-not-showing?rq=1)