# No task bar appearing

Tags: taskbar, minimize

this is pretty strange and I have no idea if I just pressed something, or if something is wrong with Ubuntu its self, but for some reason I have no task bar, the top bar, or even exit/minimize/full screen buttons. I don't really know what to search so I was hoping someone here could help me out with this issue. I've tried restarting my computer but when I login it just disables everything again.

[image]

Comment: Possible Duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/285779/after-upgrading-to-13-04-unity-interface-is-not-showing

Answer (score 1):

What Version of Ubuntu? because if it is a certain few all you have to do is scroll your mouse over where it was before click on settings and then appearance,behavior tab and last but not least the button for auto hide the launcher that says on or off.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you, I believe  you were right, however, for some reason the setting won't change and there's no "save" button, so when I go back to "All Settings" then back into "Appearance->Behaviour" the Auto-hide the Launcher selection is still on. Sorry, I know I sound stupid, but I'm still new in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you have *Xfce Panel Switch* among **Settings**, launch it and choose another panel configuration.