# I Installed Ubuntu 14.04 and On The First Load I Get No Desktop Just a Background and Cursor

Tags: 14.04, gui

I have used a older version of Ubuntu on another computer just like this one with the only difference being the graphics. This computer has AMD graphics. I've seen post around like this but I tried everything in them and non of the posts answers have got my computer to work. My computer is a HP Pavillion G6, AMD A4-3300M APU with Radeon HD Graphics 1.9Ghz, factory default Windows 7, 4Gb of RAM.

I had just installed Ubuntu to run along side Windows 7 from a 16Gb USB. It finished and I turned on my computer and it loaded into the grub loader ( I believe that is what it is called ) and chose Ubuntu. It loaded up, and it came to the log in screen. I logged into my account and there was nothing there. No console, no GUI, nothing but a cursor.

I would open the console but neither of my CTRL keys function on my computer. I can right click on the desktop and create documents and folders though. SO what I did to get to a terminal was to right click->create a folder->go to Computer->go to usr/bin/gnome terminal. Thats how I opened a terminal and I don't know if it will work through that correctly or not but I re-installed Ubuntu desktop and and installed Unity through the console but to no avail.

I don't know what to do and any help would be appreciated. I don't even know if I'm doing anything right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `fglrx` installation with these steps:

1. Remove/purge current fglrx and fglrx-amdcccle (If you have used a method outside of aptitude, apt, Software Center or Synaptic, follow the other party's instructions for removal). You will need to deliberately remove both the normal and -updates versions in recent releases of Ubuntu because it seems that attempting to remove one installs the other:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*
   ```
2. Reboot.
3. You may need to install the linux generic headers

   ```
   sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
   ```
4. Install the driver

   4.1. For 12.04:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
   ```

   or

   ```
   sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates
   ```

   4.2. From 14.04 forward, fglrx-amdcccle is included when you install fglrx, so the following will suffice:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install fglrx
   ```

   or

   ```
   sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates
   ```

   To install the packages for hardware acceleration along with the driver:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install fglrx xvba-va-driver libva-glx1 libva-egl1 vainfo
   ```

   or

   ```
   sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates xvba-va-driver libva-glx1 libva-egl1 vainfo
   ```
5. Generate a fresh xorg.conf **BEFORE REBOOTING**!

   ```
   sudo amdconfig --initial
   ```

   If you are using multiple AMD graphics cards or AMD dual graphics (i.e.: notebook users), use:

   ```
   sudo amdconfig --adapter=all --initial
   ```
6. Reboot again.
7. To confirm the drivers are working open a terminal and type:

   ```
   fglrxinfo
   ```

   You should get an output similar to the following:

   ```
   fglrxinfo 
   display: :0  screen: 0
   OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
   OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6300M Series
   OpenGL version string: 4.2.11733 Compatibility Profile Context
   ```

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

Comment: Okay I did this and all that happened was I logged in and did what its been doing. Should I select a different source for the drivers and see what happen?

Comment: What drivers appears?

Comment: My AMD/ATI grapchics. It says its using the recommended drivers with using the x.Org x server, but there's two more options to choose. The video driver for and graphics accelerator from fglrx (properties), or fglrx updates

Comment: What is selected? Had you tried `fglrx` driver? Can you post the output of the `unity` command?

Comment: I'm going to say what unity said that I think is important.

Comment: "Unity is not supported by your hardware. Enable software rendering instead (slow)." It then says "starting plugin: opengl" then "LLVM ERROR: Do not know how to split the result of this operator."

Comment: Simply copy the command output with `Ctrl+May+C`, open a new tab on the terminal with `Ctrl+May+T` and type `firefox`, then go to askubuntu.com and edit your post with the `unity` command output

Comment: Also when trying to use fglrx it doesn't work and reverts. It says that the package dependencies cannot be resolved.

Comment: Did you read this: http://askubuntu.com/a/286774/387382?

Comment: What package/s is missing?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by which ones are missing. I looked at the page you gave me and it didn't work. Also I cant copy and paste. My Ctrl key don't work. I tried selecting it all but Firefox would not let me paste. I kept right clicking but it didn't work.  A lot of Firefox wasn't functioning correctly.

Comment: Ok, I refered to, when you try to enable `fglrx`, what error got.