# Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't start after installation / live from USB

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb

today I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my old (x64) computer.
I installed it from a live USB stick (created with unetbootin, FAT).
After the sucessfull installation on the hard disk I rebooted the PC. The typical purple boot screen showed up but thats it.
The fans are still running, the keyboard lights are on and the displays seem to have a signal since they dont't go to standby mode.
All I say is two black screens.

Then I tried to start the live version from the stick - nothing happens. I mean really nothing happens. I click on the button at thats it. Dead end.

During the booting process there was a massage right before the purple screen. As far as I can remember it said something like:

```
no irq handler for vector 

repeated 5-7 times.
```

Comment: try to boot the machine and after the purple screen shows up , press ESC then tell what you see

Comment: I tried but it vanished way to fast. Is there any possibility to pause it?

Comment: also after the purple screen there's a black screen where I can move my mouse.

Answer (score 0):

try to do the following:
- press this key combination simultaneously `Ctrl+Alt+F2`
- a regular command line screen will appear , type in your username and password as configured during install process
- when the prompt turn to something like `user@machine:~$` type this

`sudo pkill X`

beware that X is uppercase
- then type

```
sudo startx
```

if this didn't work comeback here :)

Comment: thanks, I rebooted after that and now I seem to have a new problem: I can now see the login screen and if I type in the password it kind of "refreshs" the screen and I have to type it in again. Like an infinite loop.

Comment: @zergcheese,i guess you are typing the wrong password, what is your native language and what is your keyboard layout

Comment: look above, forgot that pressing enter posts the comment :)

Comment: i don't - if I type in a wrong pw it says "wrong password" in red writing. It seems to be a similiar problem to this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/161736/ubuntu-box-just-redisplaying-login-screen-after-update
My native language is German und my keyboard layout is QWERTZ

Answer (score 0):

It could be graphics problem, or problem with Unity.

When your machine gets to that purple screen, try to press Ctrl+Alt+F2 and report if a terminal appears.

Comment: @younes good clue mate, i hope we both were thinking the same ;)

Comment: hh i guess you didn't notice my answer as we have split second difference :p